# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple piece of code in Python to try and put a text file into a list and get this error message:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

This is the code:

```
def MAINLOOP ():
    import random
    listofkeywords = []
    attempts = 0
    complete = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    while complete < 30:
        question = random.randint(0,14)
        print(question)

MAINLOOP()
def IMPORTKEYWORDS():
    thekeywords = open("keywords.txt","r")
    listofkeywords == thekeywords
```

Comment: what is the `while` loop doing there

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `while complete < 30:`?  
And what have you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: The `while` statement doesn't make sense at least for me. Is this supposed to be length or what?

Answer (score 4):

Error at line `while complete < 30`. The `complete` is a list and you try to compare it with a integer number `30`? If you want to compare the list length, use `while len(complete) < 30`.

Comment: This is not the fix. while len(complete) < 30 will cause an infinite loop in case of lists with upto 29 elements.

Comment: I just suggest the fix for TypeError?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the error is to access a specific item in the list.

```
def MAINLOOP ():
    import random
    listofkeywords = []
    attempts = 0
    complete = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

    while complete[0] < 30:
or 
    while len(complete[0]) < 30:

        question = random.randint(0,14)
        print(question)

MAINLOOP()
def IMPORTKEYWORDS():
    thekeywords = open("keywords.txt","r")
    listofkeywords == thekeywords
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing whole list at once. Such comparisons are not supported unless you use numpy. Fix for your code is to compare each entry in list individually as follows:

```
def MAINLOOP ():
    import random
    listofkeywords = []
    attempts = 0
    complete = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    for i in complete:
        if i <30:
            question = random.randint(0,14)
            print(question)

MAINLOOP()
def IMPORTKEYWORDS():
    thekeywords = open("keywords.txt","r")
    listofkeywords == thekeywords
```

Answer (score 0):

because complete is a tuple and there is a list inside it then first you should get first element which is the list

you can use index like below

**complete[0]**

Comment: This has been already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034746/18145256).